# How can I shutdown, restart, log out using HUD?

Tags: session, hud

Is it possible to add session command such as shutdown, restart, log out using HUD or taking advantage of HUD?

I'm waiting for meaningful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Shut down and Log out are already available using HUD, just type either of the two and it should display:

> Device > Shut down...

for example.

If you type Shut down, a dialog window will open which has *Reboot / Restart as an option* (located on the bottom left corner).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HUD to Shut down and log out.

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  That will allow you to Shutdown, and logout.  When you choose shutdown, that will give the option to Reboot.